# Centralizar <label> no centro da tela

Tags: html5, css3

Olá alguém me pode ajudar como eu faço para centralizar estas labels?

PS: O text-align: center; não funciona!

```
<label class="emp">IMM</label> <label class="service">Home Gateway</label>
```

Podem ver e testar o código abaixo:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div#bar{
  background: #424041;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}
.emp{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #377486;
}
.service{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}
.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 4% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.form .botao {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: 0;
  background: #377486;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
  transition: all 0.3 ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.form .botao:hover,.form .botao:active,.form .botao:focus {
  background: #336675;
}
body {
  background: #4d4b4c; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #4d4b4c, #4d4b4c);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #4d4b4c, #4d4b4c);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #4d4b4c, #4d4b4c);
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #4d4b4c, #4d4b4c);
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;      
}
.form .name{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
.form .message {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.form .message a {
  color: #4CAF50;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <!-- Não andamos a reboque dos que nos querem domar, para o futuro ser bem nosso e não sermos pele e osso -->
 <!-- judas vais rebentar judas vais rebentar tiro liro liro liro tiro liro liro lo vamos quaima-lo sem dó vamos queima-lo sem dó -->
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>IMM Home Gateway</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bar">
<label class="emp">IMM</label> <label class="service">Home Gateway</label>
</div>
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form" id="login">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Utilizador:" autocomplete="off" name="user" id="user" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass" id="pass" />
      <input type="hidden" name="ToProc" value="login-form" id="ToProc">
      <input type="submit" class="botao" value="Logar" id="entrar" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Utilizar `display: inline-block`, na classe `.emp`. Pois label não se comporta como uma letra por padrão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo o que vi do teu código, basta colocar a div com id bar com 100% de largurar e align center que vai ficar centralizado.

```
div#bar {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

as demais regras que você já tem, continua aplicando, mas para o que precisa apenas isso resolve

Answer (score 2):

Só colocar um ***text-align: center;*** na div com id ***"bar"*** que resulta da maneira que quer!

```
div#bar {
    background: #424041;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
}
```